# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.mail.util.MessageRemovedIOException

Tags: java, java-8, jakarta-mail, noclassdeffounderror

While upgrading application from jdk6 to jdk8, we are getting following error on `Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);`

```
 SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [] threw exception [java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.mail.util.MessageRemovedIOException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
```

Has anyone faced the same or related issue while upgrading their java app ?

EDIT: the same code is working with java6.

Comment: quick googling gave me https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj11eT18qjJAhUFND4KHR1uDo8QFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mkyong.com%2Fjava%2Fjava-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-sun-mail-util-messageremovedioexception%2F&usg=AFQjCNHEdjx7to1UHTQK1Fyh0_BQN6J_8A&sig2=T0QbxB0LOXPgLMzJGntiHA

Comment: yeah... I've already tried this one.

Comment: can you please paste here your piece of code that throws this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a mix of JavaMail classes from different versions of JavaMail in your classpath.  What application server are you using and what's in the lib directory of your web application?

Answer (score 3):

i used this and it worked:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. I am using Maven dependencies to 
configure external libraries.

The problem was resolved by switching from the new maven repository 
for the Java Mail Api, to the old Maven repository

New Repository(raises the exception):
    
            javax.mail
            javax.mail-api
            1.5.5

Old repository(works fine):
    
            javax.mail
            mail
            1.4

I have no idea why using the old repository works, and using the new one doesn't. It would be great if someone was to clarify this.